# C# dynamic classes at run-time?

Tags: c#, dynamic

First, I am not talking about the new 'dynamic' keyword n C# 4.0.  :)  I believe I need to go the other way...

I want a class, at code/design-time, that is generated from a set of XML files, or files/folder combinations, etc.  Anything I can do with a change to the extern source.

Is this possible with C#?  I know it is possible with some design-time compliation of some hidden class name or something (i.e. the built in Properties for each project).

Is there an easier way to do this?  ALmost like a dynamic enum?  Here's what I am trying to do:

```
public static class MenuItems
{
}
```

And at design-time, I want the properties (or methods/fields, if that's easier) added based on an XML file definition.  Like:

```
<MenuItems>
  <Item>Homepage</Item>
  <Item>Portfolio</Item>
  <Item>About</Item>
  <Item>Contact</Item>
</MenuItem>
```

Then, while coding in the designer I would have intellisense like:

```
if (page.ToString == MenuItems.Homepage)...
if (page.ToString == MenuItems.Portfolio)...
```

Notice how the properties were defined in the XML, and added to the class at design time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `partial` classes might be of help.

Comment: Are you looking for a similar experience to C# code is generated for resource files?

Comment: @nader: Yes, almost exactly that experience!  You generate a new entry in the Resource, and you have it available at design time with ResourceManager.MyResourceName.  Yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate source code.  It is well supported by Microsoft and is used on several projects including ASP.NET MVC, and soon the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Comment: Excellent point.  But, T4 templates have to generate the source code.  I am looking for a dynamic solution.  Almost realtime changes taking effect.

Comment: Marking this as the answer for now.  Seems I want too much from C#.  :)

Comment: If you want your class to be generated entirely at run-time, then how is the rest of your code (which references members of that class) is supposed to compile? Or where would IDE obtain information needed to show IntelliSense tips from?

Comment: I don't think you can -- not at runtime.  I think this question may be mis-titled.  The body of the question describes a compile-time feature more than a run-time one.

Answer (score 1):

If I may direct your attention to the [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx), and the [Web.sitemap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemap(VS.80).aspx), perhaps it will be of assistance to your actual problem.

Comment: Right.  Those create design-time properties.  I'm looking for someone that has done the leg work already.  :)  Spent a few days tinkering with my own solutions that didn't work out...  :)

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to do? I'm assuming you want to either hide/show relevant links based on a role, and also prevent access based on role. What I linked does that. If you're looking at just styling based on name, you do that per-page or similar. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting the "Role" or membership in my original question.  :)  I am asking to create a dynamic class based from a config file, at runtime.  T4 Templates mentioned by Matt does it; but, it has to be compiled to generated that code ahead of time.  I am looking for something almost real-time - i.e., has a dependency on an xml file and if the xml changes, it generates a new class version.

Comment: I was inferring it from your question; that's why I asked you what you're actually doing. I'll leave you to the templating solution, or some runtime type generation using `Reflection.Emit`. Personally though, I'd avoid that at all costs and address the real issue.

Comment: Thanks silky!  Yeah, the "real issue" is MVC uses "magic strings" everywhere... No strong-typed Views or RedirectResults.  I am creating additional extensions beyond the Futures project has.