# C# dynamic classes

Tags: c#

I'm talking about something similar to `dynamic`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408658/c-dynamic-classes-at-run-time) didn't answer my question, hence this question. I want to have a class that I can add properties to at runtime. It needs to be inherited from the type `object`.

I've seen inheriting from `DynamicObject`, but it didn't state how to add properties at run-time. Could some light be shed on this for me pls?

I have a class like this:

```
public class SomeModel : DynamicObject {
       public string SomeMandatoryProperty {get; set;}
}
```

I'd like to add all properties from another class to this class at runtime. So eg.

```
SomeModel m = new SomeModel();
m = someOtherClass;
string hi = m.otherClassProp; //Property from other class is added.
string mandatory = m.SomeMandatoryProperty; //From the mandatory property set previously.
```

Comment: The answer to your previous question is the best you could have gotten. Why didn't you like it?

Comment: It uses T4 templates to generate source code. THat guy specifically said he is not talking about something like `dynamic`, I want something like `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the `ExpandoObject` as you can dynamically add properties as needed.  There isn't however a direct way to populate an instance with the values from another object easily.  You'll have to add it manually using reflection.

Do you want to write a wrapper object where you could add properties to while still accessing the inner?  You may want to consider it that way you don't have to manage two copies of values between two different object instances.  I wrote a test class to wrap string objects to demonstrate how you can do this (similar to how the `ExpandoObject` works).  It should give you an idea on how you can do this for your types.

```
class DynamicString : DynamicObject
{
    static readonly Type strType = typeof(string);
    private string instance;
    private Dictionary<string, object> dynProperties;
    public DynamicString(string instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
        dynProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public string GetPrefixString(string prefix)
    {
        return String.Concat(prefix, instance);
    }
    public string GetSuffixString(string suffix)
    {
        return String.Concat(instance, suffix);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return instance;
    }
    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Type != typeof(string))
            return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
        result = instance;
        return true;
    }
    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        var method = strType.GetMethod(binder.Name, args.Select(a => a.GetType()).ToArray());
        if (method == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        result = method.Invoke(instance, args);
        return true;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var members = strType.GetMember(binder.Name);
        if (members.Length > 0)
        {
            var member = members.Single();
            switch (member.MemberType)
            {
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                result = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(instance, null);
                return true;
                break;
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                result = ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(instance);
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return dynProperties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        var ret = base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
        if (ret) return true;
        dynProperties[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to be adventurous, you can define your own meta objects to handle the bindings.  You could end up with reusable meta objects for different types and simplify your code immensely.  I've been playing with this for a while and have this so far.  It doesn't handle dynamically adding properties yet.  I won't be working on this any further but I'll just leave it here for reference.

```
class DynamicString : DynamicObject
{
    class DynamicStringMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
    {
        public DynamicStringMetaObject(Expression parameter, object value)
            : base(parameter, BindingRestrictions.Empty, value)
        {
        }
        public override DynamicMetaObject BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
        {
            if (binder.Type == typeof(string))
            {
                var valueType = Value.GetType();
                return new DynamicMetaObject(
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                        Expression.Convert(Expression, valueType),
                        valueType.GetProperty("Instance")),
                    BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, valueType));
            }
            return base.BindConvert(binder);
        }
        public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("BindGetMember: {0}", binder.Name));
            var valueType = Value.GetType();
            var self = Expression.Convert(Expression, valueType);
            var valueMembers = valueType.GetMember(binder.Name);
            if (valueMembers.Length > 0)
            {
                return BindGetMember(self, valueMembers.Single());
            }
            var members = typeof(string).GetMember(binder.Name);
            if (members.Length > 0)
            {
                var instance =
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                        self,
                        valueType.GetProperty("Instance"));
                return BindGetMember(instance, members.Single());
            }
            return base.BindGetMember(binder);
        }
        private DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(Expression instance, MemberInfo member)
        {
            return new DynamicMetaObject(
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(instance, member),
                    typeof(object)),
                BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, Value.GetType())
            );
        }
    }
    public string Instance { get; private set; }
    public DynamicString(string instance)
    {
        Instance = instance;
    }
    public override DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new DynamicStringMetaObject(parameter, this);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Instance;
    }
    public string GetPrefixString(string prefix)
    {
        return String.Concat(prefix, Instance);
    }
    public string GetSuffixString(string suffix)
    {
        return String.Concat(Instance, suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this will be very slow if I'm converting thousands of objects. right?

Comment: @Lol: If using a wrapped object, it will be significantly faster than using the ExpandoObject since you're not copying values around but delegating everything to the wrapped object.  After that, both should perform similarly as both approaches operate similarly.  And yes, it will be relatively slow by virtue of using dynamic types due to the reflection involved.  At this point, you have to decide whether you want to pay for it (in speed) in copying values around or in using reflection.  With thousands of objects, I'd stick with reflection.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx):

> The ExpandoObject class enables you to
>   add and delete members of its
>   instances at run time and also to set
>   and get values of these members. This
>   class supports dynamic binding, which
>   enables you to use standard syntax
>   like sampleObject.sampleMember instead
>   of more complex syntax like
>   sampleObject.GetAttribute("sampleMember").

```
dynamic manager;

manager = new ExpandoObject();
manager.Name = "Allison Brown";
manager.Age = 42;
manager.TeamSize = 10;
```

Comment: is there a way to merge properties of another class to this?

Comment: You could use reflection to do that, I don't know of any other more straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make use of [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) instead. An [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) can have members added or removed at runtime and has very nice support if you want to convert to XML etc.

From MSDN Documentation:

```
    dynamic employee, manager;

    employee = new ExpandoObject();
    employee.Name = "John Smith";
    employee.Age = 33;

    manager = new ExpandoObject();
    manager.Name = "Allison Brown";
    manager.Age = 42;
    manager.TeamSize = 10;
```